# How to add the search domain to a windows 8.1 autounattend.xml

Tags: xml, windows, headless, packer

I have a autunattend.xml file for a windows 8.1 installation with packer. This works actually ok, but it does not add to my search domain (I hope this is the right term).

So I have a VM at the end and when I try to connect to another machine in the network - lets call it **foo** - this is not working:

```
nslookp foo
```

which means, it cannot find the machine.
Adding the domain to it does work though

```
nslookup foo.company.local
```

How can I add the domain **company.local** to the autounattend.xml so that the first call is working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to add the following command in your `autounattend.xml` file

```
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
     <Description>Set DNS Search Order</Description>
     <Order>99</Order>
     <CommandLine>cmd.exe /c wmic nicconfig call SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder (company.local,<add other if necessary separated by ,)</CommandLine>
</SynchronousCommand>
```

Just make sure the Order (here 99) does not conflict with an existing command from your script

Comment: Thanks for this. This helped actually for the console. **nslookup foo** now prints out the right name with domain and the ip etc. But unfortunately the browser does not understand it. if I type **foo** as host in the browser (chrome), I still get an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. It seems I need to do more ?

Comment: dunno, how does chrome manages this ? sounds like its using a different dns resolver, does it work with IE (I guess it should use the system one)

Comment: It also does not help to enter *foo.company.local* in the browser. There only the ip is working

Comment: You are right - IE is understanding it - so I need to find out what Chrome is doing... Thanks for help

Comment: could not reproduce it at the end - now everything is working as expected

Comment: ok good to know, maybe some cache or sync issue between os and chrome